# Injecting arguments into Akka Props and Creator instances

Tags: java, akka

Akka Java here.

If I have the following actor:

```
// Groovy pseudo-code.
class Fizz extends UntypedActor {
    Buzz buzz
    String serviceURL

    Fizz(Buzz buzz, String serviceURL) {
        super()

        this.buzz = buzz
        this.serviceURL = serviceURL
    }

    static Props props() {
        Props.create(new Creator<ActorRef>() {
            @Override
            ActorRef create() throws Exception {
                new Fizz() // <— but I’d like to create a Fizz with a 
                           // particular buzz/serviceURL
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    void onReceive(Object msg) {
        // etc.
    }
}
```

And I want to create an instance (`ActorRef`) of that actor, then from the docs/code examples I’ve found, it seems that I can do this:

```
actorSystem.actorOf(Props.create(Fizz), “fizz")
```

**Can I assume that the `Props.create(Fizz)` call invokes the static `Fizz.props()` method, thereby returning the new `Fizz` instance?**

If so, then I’m wondering how I can pass arguments to the constructor. According to the [Java API docs](http://doc.akka.io/japi/akka/2.4-M3/akka/actor/Props.html#create-java.lang.Class-scala.collection.Seq-), there is a `Props.create(Class<T> clazz, Object…args)` overload, but I don’t see how I could then pass `args` on to `Fizz.props()` which takes no arguments.

Either way, I’m looking for a concrete Java example that shows how I could modify the `actorSystem.actorOf(Props.create(Fizz.class), “fizz”)` call to pass in the `buzz` and `serviceURL` arguments. I need this because I will end up having many `Fizz` instances, each with different `buzz` and `serviceURL` arguments/configs.

Comment: since there is changes in the version it would be nice to see which akka version you are using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it doesn't invoke your props method.

(with Akka 2.3.8): Using the [overload](http://doc.akka.io/japi/akka/2.3.8/akka/actor/Props.html) in your example (w/ Java 8 for brevity):

```
public static Props props(Buzz buzz, String url) {
    Props.create(Fizz.class, () -> buzz, url);
}
```

You'll have to explicitly call it on creation to get the correct `Props`:

```
ActorRef fizzActor = system.actorOf(
    Fizz.props(buzzObject, "somestring"), "actor_name");
```

Comment: Thanks @Chris Mowforth (+1) - instead of calling `Props.create(Fizz.class, () -> buzz, url)`, could I use a `Creator<Fizz>` such as `Props.create(new Creator<Fizz>()...)`, etc.? Any advantages to using a `Creator<Fizz>`?

Comment: @smeeb sure, you can do that if you want- I switched the explicit creator declaration for a lambda for clarity and explicitly declared the actor type, but it's not necessary. Is that what you mean?